# How to apply aspect-ratio media query

Tags: css, image, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I am trying to modify the size of my images based on their initial aspect-ratio. For this purpose i created 2 media on the aspect-ratio but for some reasons only the first @media applies to all images regardless of the aspect-ratio of each image.

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {
          .Visible {
    
            max-width: calc(60% - 400px);
            height: auto;
          }
         
    
        }
    
@media (aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
         .Visible {
    
            max-width: calc(60% - 80px);
            height: auto;
          }
        }
```

I tried different combinations but still not getting the desired result. Any suggestions?

Comment: @media queries are testing the aspect ratio of the viewport, not the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need some tricky point, if you update your max aspect ratio to 3/4 nested of min and make min ratio is 4/3 then your code will work...

Maybe your issue on first media query its executed since it 3/4 all the time, and aspect ratio 4/3 its fit so that will not execute else on spesfic ratio

```css
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {
    div {
    background: orange;
  }
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
    div {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Watch this element as you resize your viewport's width and height.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I had already tried this but then only the second @media is applied and the first one is lost for some reasons. I am wonderin, are we sure that this media query is able to see the  actual aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: Maybe the issue is that one image is 4/3 and another one is 3/4 but the media sees both as haveing the same aspect ratio. Do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: You are welcome, the aspect ratio used to screen at all, not for specific element, so that if image ratio is 3/4 and another one is 4/3 will not change or render style base on image...to check what I say, try to resize screen and you will see the text will be orange and when you minimize it to smallest size you will see orange color...

Comment: I understand your point but that's not excactly what i am trying to achieve. I need to apply a differend style (size) to images with different aspect ratio. Do you know how to achieve that? Thanks